# Generics in Java, and extending classes

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a method that get a B that extends `SearchBoard(interface)`, and an `M` that extends `BoardMove(interface)`.

Now I have written `CrossWord(interface)`, and `MyCrossWord` that implements `CrossWord`, but my method is not willing to recognize `MyCrossWord` as a legit `SearchBoard` obj.. 
I know I did something wrong with the generics someplace.

Comment: Please explain the phenomenon by adding the concrete class structure instead of explaining it linguistically.

Comment: If `MyCrossWord` implements `CrossWord`, why should it be recognized as a `SearchBoard`? Does `CrossWord` also extend `SearchBoard`?

Comment: yes, sorry..crossWord extends SearchBoard

Comment: ill try to add code, it will take me some time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<B extends SearchBoard, M extends BoardMove> void someMethod(B board, M move) {
...
}
```

As long as B is either SearchBoard, CrossWord or MyCrossWord, it should accept a MyCrossWord as first argument.

Comment: Which is entirely pointless. You might as well write `void someMethod(SearchBoard board, BoardMove move) {`.

Comment: That's not exactly the same, but anyway it seems to be what he described he's doing.  Either way it should accept an instance of MyCrossWord if that implements CrossWord which extends SearchBoard.  Also, I wrote the type parameters as method type parameters here to make it short, but they may be class parameters.